# Require is not defined even with webpack

Tags: javascript, node.js, web, webpack

I'm working with webpack 5 in a web app that uses node modules. When I run my `index.html` with a local server I get this error `Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined`.

I have this folder structure:

```
my_project/
├── node_modules
├── dist/
│    └── main.js
├── src 
│    ├── index.js
│    └── index.html
├── package-lock.json
├── package.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

My `webpack.config.js` is:

```
 // 'webpack-node-externals' is needed because I'm getting the error cannot resolve "http"

const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')


module.exports = {

  target: 'web',
  externals: [nodeExternals()],

  resolve: {
    fallback: {
      util: require.resolve("util/")
    },
    modules: ['./dist/', './node_modules']
  }
};
```

And my `index.js` is:

```
const Binance = require('node-binance-api');
const binance = new Binance().options({
  APIKEY: '',
  APISECRET: ''
});

console.log(binance)
```

After run `webpack` in the terminal,the `main.js` is created into the `dist` folder.
Finally, I import `main.js` into `index.html` like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../dist/main.js"></script>
```

Comment: it's because the package you use `node-binance-api` only is only able to run in node environment instead of web.

Comment: But it works fine with browserify. I just wanted to test it with webpack